# Using a while loop with try and except to get user input

Tags: python, while-loop, try-catch, raw-input, except

My code is creating an infinite loop when I enter a letter at the command prompt.  I think that **len(sys.argv) > 1** is causing the problem, since if I enter a letter at the command prompt this will always be true and the loop will not end.  Not sure how I could work around this though... any advice for this newbie would be helpful.  Thanks!

```
"""
Have a hard-coded upper line, n.
Print "Fizz buzz counting up to n", substituting in the number we'll be counting up to.
Print out each number from 1 to n, replacing with Fizzes and Buzzes as appropriate.
Print the digits rather than the text representation of the number (i.e. print 13 rather than thirteen).
Each number should be printed on a new line.
"""

# entering number at command line: working
# entering letter at command line: infinite loop
# entering number at raw_input: works, runs process
# entering letter at raw_input: working

import sys

n = ''

while type(n)!=int:
    try:
        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            n = int(sys.argv[1])
        else:
             n = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number...")
        continue

print("Fizz buzz counting up to {}".format(n))
for y in range(1,n+1):
    if y % 5 == 0 and y % 3 == 0:
        print('fizzbuzz')
    elif y % 3 == 0:
        print('fizz')
    elif y % 5 == 0:
        print('buzz')
    else:
        print(y)`enter code here`
```

Comment: why are you using sys.argv?

Comment: what is your error, actually? The code works fine on my machine...

Comment: He's using sys.argv because he wants the user to have the option to enter a number as an argument when the script is initially called

Comment: @SwankSwashbucklers, I am talking about why the OP is using it in the loop

Comment: Thanks for all the comments!  Taking all the sys.argv stuff out of the while loop seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting first catching a value and index error:

```
import sys

try:
    n = int(sys.argv[1])
except (IndexError,ValueError):
    while True:
         try:
            n = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
            break
         except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number...")

print("Fizz buzz counting up to {}".format(n))
for y in range(1,n+1):
    if y % 5 == 0 and y % 3 == 0:
        print('fizzbuzz')
    elif y % 3 == 0:
        print('fizz')
    elif y % 5 == 0:
        print('buzz')
    else:
        print(y)
```

If you are not actually trying to take command line inputs just use the while True:

```
while True: 
     try:
        n = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
        break # input was valid so break the loop
     except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number...")

    print("Fizz buzz counting up to {}".format(n))
    for y in range(1,n+1):
        if y % 5 == 0 and y % 3 == 0:
            print('fizzbuzz')
        elif y % 3 == 0:
            print('fizz')
        elif y % 5 == 0:
            print('buzz')
        else:
            print(y)
```

Comment: Nice, cleaner than what I had, but that `continue` in the except isn't needed is it?

Comment: @SwankSwashbucklers, yep,  the joys of copy pasting code.